# Chart.js - Polar Area with multiple Datasets

Tags: chart.js

Guys I am not able to put multiple data fields in 'datasets' properly, or say dividing polar area into 2 or more groups with different dataset. I am getting view like this when using the below code.

```
var birdsData = {
    labels: ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [1,5,7,2,5,0,0,0,0,0],
        backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)",
            "rgba(100, 255, 0, 0.8)",
            "rgba(200, 50, 255, 0.8)",
            "rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.8)",
            "rgba(100, 255, 0, 0.8)"
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: [
            "#CCC",
            "#CCC",
            "#CCC",
            "#CCC",
            "#CCC"
        ]
  },{
      label: '# of Votes',
    data: [0,0,0,0,0,1,5,7,2,5],
    backgroundColor: [
      "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.8)",
      "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.8)",
      "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.8)",
      "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.8)",
      "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.8)",
      "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.8)",
      "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.8)",
      "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.8)",
      "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.8)",
      "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.8)"
    ]
  }]
};
```

[image: image for reference]

Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: Do you need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/9udoy2mf/?

Comment: @beaver yeah something like it, but could we divide them into 4 groups, 90deg each exactly, with each group can contain 2-4 bars.